# PowerShell: простейший пример программы для установки npm и composer зависимостей разом

Tags: npm, powershell, composer

Для тех, кто знаком с такими пакетными менеджерами, как **npm** и **composer**, очевидно, что зависимости для каждого из них нужно устанавливать отдельно. Никогда не использовал PowerShell, но вероятно, с его помощью можно выполнить команды `npm install` и `composer install` разом (параллельно или последовательно). Если это действительно возможно, то как будет выглядеть этот простой скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант -- использовать стандартный CMDlet `Start-Process`.

Шапка скрипта (позаботимся об ошибках заранее; пригодится в обоих случаях):

```
# Error handling
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
trap {$_; exit 1}
```

- **Последовательный** вариант (дольше, но безопаснее и больше контроля):

  ```
  Start-Process 'C:\Path\To\npm.exe' -ArgumentList 'install' -Wait -NoNewWindow
  Start-Process 'C:\Path\To\composer.exe' -ArgumentList 'install' -Wait -NoNewWindow
  ```
- **Параллельный** вариант (быстрее засчёт параллельности, но не учитывает падения одного из процессов):

  ```
  $npm = Start-Process 'C:\Path\To\npm.exe' -ArgumentList 'install' -PassThru
  $composer = Start-Process 'C:\Path\To\composer.exe' -ArgumentList 'install' -PassThru

  while (!$npm.HasExited -AND !$composer.HasExited) {
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
  }

  if ($npm.ExitCode -ne 0) {
      throw "ERROR: NPM exited with code $($npm.ExitCode)!"
  }

  if ($composer.ExitCode -ne 0) {
      throw "ERROR: COMPOSER exited with code $($composer.ExitCode)!"
  }
  ```

В первом случае вы получите весь вывод в консоль и сможете проследить весь процесс. Во втором (при условии успеха) всё будет (в два раза?) быстрее, но если один из процессов свалится -- вы не узнаете, почему.

---

*P.S. да, можно написать через .NET методы и проверять и на падение, и ExitCode, и даже перехватывать вывод, но как по мне -- это переусложнение, и использоваться должно только опытными юзерами powershell-а, которые чётко понимают, что они делают, зачем и почему используют для этих целей powershell.*

Comment: Благодарю Вас за качественный ответ!